# Bootstrap menu on hover darken background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the following menu effect
http://www.porsche.com/usa/

when you hover on menu the page gets an overlay with black opacity. I am using twitter bootstrap but I can't make this exactly work

My thought is to use

```
// overlay all when
$('.dropdown').mouseenter('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    //ADD HERE JS + CSS MAGIC
})
$('.dropdown').mouseleave('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    //ADD HERE JS + CSS MAGIC    
})
```

but I can't figure out how to make any div with overlay to show just below my menu and keep my submenu above the overlay. Also how to make this solution to work using also an affixed menu

Thanks in advance for your time and effort

Comment: I would be very helpful if you placed some sample code on fiddle.js or at least in your post so we can copy it and help.

Comment: it is the normal bootstrap dropdown menu
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.nav.navbar-nav a').hover(
        function () {
            $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 1, "visibility": "visible"});
        }, function () {
                         $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});
        }
);
```

```css
.slider-opacity{
    background-color: rgba(127, 186,0, 0.7);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    opacity: 0;   
    visibility: hidden;

    transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="slider-opacity"></div>
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

it's help.

HTML SCRIPT

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="slider-opacity"></div>
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS SCRIPT

```
.slider-opacity{
    background-color: rgba(127, 186,0, 0.7);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    opacity: 0;   
    visibility: hidden;

    transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;

}
```

JS SCRIPT

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav a').hover(
        function () {
            $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 1, "visibility": "visible"});
        }, function () {
                         $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});
        }
);
```

Comment: Welcome ... this is right answer. please add right answer and give me points.