# Bootstrap menu on hover darken background > flickering issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, hover, flicker

I have tried to implement an opacity effect to my website following this thread: [Bootstrap menu on hover darken background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928288/bootstrap-menu-on-hover-darken-background)

Now the navigation Dropdown won't open correctly anymore and the whole Page starts flickering while hovering the Navigation.
Watch here: http://tekfreak.de

Custom.css:

```css
.slider-opacity{
    background-color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.7);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;

    opacity: 0;   
    visibility: hidden;

    transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;

}
```

HTML:

```html
{* desktop navigation (> screen-min-sm) *}
{strip}
<div id="evo-main-nav-wrapper" class="nav-wrapper{if $Einstellungen.template.theme.static_header === 'Y'} do-affix{/if}">
    <nav id="evo-main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container{if $Einstellungen.template.theme.static_header === 'N' || isset($Einstellungen.template.theme.pagelayout) && $Einstellungen.template.theme.pagelayout !== 'fluid'}-fluid{/if}">
            {if $Einstellungen.template.theme.static_header === 'Y'}
                <div class="navbar-header visible-affix pull-left hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{$ShopURL}" title="{$Einstellungen.global.global_shopname}">
                        {if isset($ShopLogoURL)}
                            {image src=$ShopLogoURL alt=$Einstellungen.global.global_shopname class="img-responsive-height"}
                        {/if}
                    </a>
                </div>
            {/if}
            <div class="megamenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav force-float">
                    {include file='snippets/categories_mega.tpl'}
                    {if $Einstellungen.template.theme.static_header === 'Y'}
                        <li class="cart-menu visible-affix dropdown bs-hover-enabled pull-right{if $nSeitenTyp == 3} current{/if}" data-toggle="basket-items">
                            {include file='basket/cart_dropdown_label.tpl'}
                        </li>
                    {/if}
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
{/strip}
<div class="slider-opacity"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tekfreak.de/templates/Evo/js/navopacity.js"></script>
```

JS that is linked in the HTML File:

```js
$('.nav.navbar-nav').hover(
  function () {
    $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 1, "visibility": "visible"});
  }, function () {
    $('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});
  }
);
```

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Try this - `$('.nav.navbar-nav li a').on('mouseover',function(){$('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 1, "visibility": "visible"});}).on('mouseout',function(){$('.slider-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});
});` Attach it to `li` `a` instead of `ul`

Comment: Unfortunally has the same flickering Effect... But sometimes the dropdown opens..... Tried it at `ul` `li` & `a` > Watch here: http://tekfreak.de

Comment: Can't tell what's happening exactly buddy.. But its just event triggering is not being handled well.. If you google you will get just CSS solutions too instead of this jquery...

Comment: Thanks, i will try to find something...

Comment: the problem seems to be, that when the div "slider-opacity" changes the visibility to "1" so that this div gets between the mouse and the mouseover-object. as it detects then, ther is no mouseover trigger anymore the "slider-opacity" changes the visibility back to "0". as the mouse is still on the same position, the mouseover gets detected again and the "slider-opacity" changes the visibility to "1" again.... seems to be a loop....... if i could change the mouseover object to "z-index 2" while mouse over, the loop should be broken..... but how do i do this?!

Comment: Just keep in mind that your `.nav.navbar-nav` element's `z-index` should be greater than `.slider-opacity`.. This should probably solve the problem..